# Float number multiplication result

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a multiplication on a float number but the result doesn't display the float.

```
$diver->prix_unitaire = $prix_unitaire;
$montant_total = $prix_unitaire * 1;
$diver->prix_total = $montant_total;
dd($diver);
```

I get 1500 and but it should be 1500,25. Could someone help me?

```
#attributes: array:6 [▼
    "facture_id" => 3
    "quantite" => "2"
    "dt_amende" => Carbon @1513798542 {#1030 ▶}
    "saison_id" => 1
    "prix_unitaire" => "1500,25"
    "prix_total" => 1500
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `prix_unitaire` is not in `float` format. You should format it to float first and then convert it:

```
$prix_unitaire = floatval(str_replace(",",".",$prix_unitaire));
$montant_total = $prix_unitaire * 1;
```

Comment: I'm glad to know it helps you! Can you accept it as the correct answer, please?